# Unable to connect to DB using Mysqlworkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, docker

I am running a Mysql db inside docker container as shown below:
[image]

Adding a new user from within the container and logging in with same user works fine within the container but the same doesnt work when i try to connect from the workbench:

[image]

However the login works fine as a root user both from within the container as well as the workbench.

Comment: Are you mapping the MySQL port when start the container?

Comment: it's able to connect, seems like something is wrong with credentials

Comment: There is something wrong with my user creation script:
When i try to create user like 'sample_user'@'localhost' the login fails whereas if the user name is 'sample_user' the login works fine. What is the difference between both user creation approaches?

Comment: The @localhost. It’s saying only allow logins locally. You should be able to change that to @% and it will work externally.